# Selenium : NullPointerException error on finding element though xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, nullpointerexception

I am searching for element with dynamic ID. I have written below code to add those elements into List List3. But it throws NullPointerException erro:

```
public void markAnswers()
        {
            List<WebElement> List1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='id1']/ul/li"));
            List<WebElement> List2 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='id2']/div"));

            System.out.println(List1.size());
            String str;
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
            for(WebElement el: List2)
            {
                str=el.getAttribute("id");
                System.out.println(str);                        
                Utilities.waitFor(5000);
                WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='"+str+"']/div[4]/div[1]/ul[1]/li/input"));
                element.click();
                element.getAttribute("innerHTML");
                List3.add(element);
            }   
        }
```

Please help.

Comment: Edit your answer and add the detailed exception. Is NullPointerException thrown here `element.click();` ?

Comment: Does that element exist? (Is XPath good?) If you are using Chrome, go to a console and type `$x('//div[@id="YOUR_STRING"]/div[4]/div[1]/ul[1]/li/input')` to see if you can find it without Selenium.

Comment: May be your getting that exception at getAttribute("id") method, I think that 'ID' is not available in the list elements. Check that once. Or else you can post your HTML code.

Comment: Where have you created instance on Web driver.May be driver is not initialized before you use it.

Comment: getAttribute("id") prints correct ID. The Xpath is correct . I verified it in firefox

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at pages.participantSide.ParticipantLogin.markAnswers(ParticipantLogin.java:139)

Comment: Driver has been initialized as I can call and execute other methods. Exception arises at element.getAttribute("innerHTML");

Comment: @Abhinav Can u pls post the html source of the element....

Comment: @Vicky Please find below HTML source:<ul>
<li>
<input id="id1" class="class1" type="radio" onclick="function;" name="name1"/>                    a                      
<div style="max-width:400px;max-height: 300px;overflow: auto;">
</li>
</ul>

Comment: @Abhinav Do you want to get the text "a" from the above source

Comment: @Vicky No I want to click on the WebElement which is a radio button. But it gives NullPointer Exception.

Comment: @Abhinav for what purpose have you used element.getAttribute("innerHTML");

Comment: Why are you getting list of elements. You can use direct xpath of radio button to select it. Use this line to select radio button: ' driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='id1']")).click();

Comment: Those IDs are also dynamics. However I resolved my issue. There was anissue with initialization of list. Many Thanks to all for help.!!

Comment: Why did you created new list..driver.findElements() will return list na.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List was not properly initialized. Initialized as below and issue was resolved:

```
List<WebElement> List1 = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
```

Answer (score 0):

@Abhinav - You have initialized list properly, but you might not have added correct package. Check whether you have imported below package:

import java.util.List;

with above import, following which you have used should work fine:-
List List1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='id1']/ul/li"));

Comment: I have imported this package and it is able to findelements. The problem was with initialization and doing modification issue was resolved. Thanks.